# MenuItem вне Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml

Можно ли использовать `MenuItem` вне `Menu`? Мне нужен один `MenuItem` нажав на который popup покажет еще несколько `MenuItem`'ов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня криво показывает шаблон и popup вообще не открывается.

Comment: Ничего не понял, можете подробнее описать проблему?

Comment: @АндрейNOP MenuItem работает только внутри Menu, а мне нужно вставить MenuItem в Grid

Comment: Если ответ вам помог - отметьте его галочкой. Если нет - напишите что конкретно не получается, будем думать дальше.

Answer (score 3):

Вам не нужно использовать `MenuItem` вне `Menu`, вам нужно просто у корневого `MenuItem` изменить шаблон. С `MenuItem` в штатном комплекте поставляется 4 шаблона: элемент меню верхнего уровня без дочерних элементов, элемент меню верхнего уровня с дочерними элементами, элемент подменю без дочерних элементов, элемент подменю с дочерними элементами. Вам нужен как раз последний шаблон:

```
<Menu Background="Transparent">
    <MenuItem Header="111" Template="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}">
        <MenuItem Header="222"/>
        <MenuItem Header="333">
            <MenuItem Header="444"/>
            <MenuItem Header="555"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если ваше меню будет содержать несколько пунктов, то имеет смысл вынести установку шаблона в стиль и разместить пункты меню вертикально:

```
<Menu Background="Transparent">
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuItemTemplateKey}}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static MenuItem.SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="111">
        <MenuItem Header="222"/>
        <MenuItem Header="333">
            <MenuItem Header="444"/>
            <MenuItem Header="555"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="666">
        <MenuItem Header="777"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]